# How to calculate balanced tiers on ranked values

Tags: javascript, math, google-apps-script

I have an array of ranked values that I would like to group by x number of tiers for a given report. In this example, I have a list of 20 items and would like to calculate a total of 5 tiers so that the tiers are as evenly spread out as possible. In other cases, there might be a total of 31 items and 4 tiers. How could I write a function to handle this? Below are sample data and what the calculated tier for each item should be.

[image]

The reason why I would like to do this is to examine a difference in trends based upon the volume of included metrics. The table above is an example only because the data I am actually working with is not something I can share.

Comment: I know it has something to do with using modulus, but whatever I have come up with, it's not working like it should.

Comment: Good work! You should move your update into an answer and accept it the next day

Comment: Thanks, I took your suggestion and did so.

Comment: @Parker Why did you vote to put this question on hold?

Comment: It was too broad originally, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It's better to ask a specific question / show what you've attempted instead of just asking "how do I do x?". It's nothing held against you, just a notification that you should clean up the question before people can answer it :)

Comment: Okay, well I tried to do that by adding some reasoning behind why I needed to calculate balanced tiers. However, the code I was working on for it prior to posting my answer was complete mathematical garbage and would have been meaningless to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### **UPDATE**

After some testing, this is the function I came up with:

```
function getTier(num_tiers, arr_length, rank){
    var c = Math.floor(arr_length / num_tiers, 1),
    m = (rank - 1) % c;
    var result = Math.floor(((rank / c) - (m / c)) + 1, 0);
    return (result > num_tiers) ? num_tiers : result;
}
```